# Why is it when I open a new link in another window on Heroku it says "The page you were looking for doesn't exist."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I middle click a link to open in another tab. It then shows this error:

> The page you were looking for doesn't exist.
>
> You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.
>
> If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

I even copied the link, opened a tab manually, and pasted it. The path is correct. `https://tyger.ac/users/logout`. The app works fine otherwise, if it's clicked in the same window.

I suspect it might have something to do with Turbolinks, but I don't see how that would affect it. The new tab would have the same cookie!

Here is the Heroku log:

```
2014-02-12T08:24:51.455158+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/users/logout host=tyger.ac request_id=fd5e35d4-a5bc-4bde-b2d7-02fc0dd64eac fwd="xxx.15.69.66" dyno=web.2 connect=1ms service=11ms status=404 bytes=1351
```

Rails 4.0.0

Comment: What authentication system are you using? Devise?

Answer (score 0):

Oops, I forgot /users/logout is a POST request!

```
logout_users POST   /users/logout(.:format)                         users#logout
```

Answer (score 0):

Saying the app works when you use the same window could point to having perpetuation issues with your session

---

**Sessions**

I would recommend looking at how you're maintaining your users' sessions. If you're using a system such as [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), you'll be using the inbuilt [Rails sessions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html) management, which maintains even if the browser is closed

If you detail what you're using for session management, it will be a much bigger help

Comment: Sessions are cookie sessions. It was because that path is supposed to be a POST request, not GET. Should I make the path both POST & GET? If so, how?

Comment: If you need to change the path, you can use this in your link: `<%= link_to "logout", logout_path, method: :post %>`